# Problems solving the SDE $dX_t = aX_tdt +\sigma dB_t$. Why don't Ito's lemma work?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the SDE below and I am running into some problems. We're given that $X_0=1$, $a \in R$, $\sigma > 0.$  $$dX_t = aX_tdt +\sigma dB_t$$

I tried to solve it the following manner. Assuming that $X_t=f(t, B_t)$ and applying Ito's lemma yielded:

$$(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial^2 x})dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dB_t$$

Now here is where I want to match "coefficients". That is saying

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \sigma  \implies f=\sigma x + g(t)$$

Entering this into the other "coefficent" yields:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial^2 x} = g'(t) = aX_t = af=a(\sigma x+g(t))$$

Now we've arrived at a seperable ODE for $g(t)$ which when solved would yield the final solution $f(t, B_t)$. However, this doesn't work, and looking at the solution set I am completely off target. My question is why is this? Why can't I solve this SDE using this method? Where is the flaw in the solution method?

The suggested solution method was to study $Y_t= e^{-at}X_t$. How on earth would you come up with this anstaz by looking purely at the SDE?

EDIT (completed tried solution):

After having said that $f= \sigma x + g(t)$ I used this fact to obtain that:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial^2 x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} =g'(t)=a(\sigma x  +g(t))$$
Now I tried to solve that ODE by the follwing processes:

$$g'(t)=a(\sigma x+g(t))\iff \int \frac{dg}{a(\sigma x + g(t))} = t + C$$

This yielded further that $g(t)=Ce^{at}-\sigma x$ and so $f=\sigma x + g(t) = Ce^{at}$. This clearly isn't the solution however.

Comment: The reason you can't solve the SDE with that method is the ODE you found for $g$ is $g'(t) = a(\sigma x + g(t))$.  The solution to this will depend on $x$, not just $t$, so $g$ is not a function of just $t$.

Comment: @user6247850 Hm. I was thinking in line of $\partial_x f = \sigma$ implies by integrating w.r.t. $x$ that $f = \sigma x + g(t)$. In this case $g(t)$ is simply a function that would disappear if we would take the derivative w.r.t $x$ again.

Comment: @SinbadTheSailor you should have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = a\,f(t,x)$ instead...and then you got $f(t,x) = f(0,x)\,\mathrm{e}^{a\,t}$.

Comment: Perhaps I am making a logcial mistake here. I am trying to say that because $\partial_x f = sigma$ I know that the form of $f$ must be $f = \sigma x + g(t)$. And then I use that fact in the other equation. I am guessing now that this is wrong? And instead I should only use that fact once to say that the second partial derivative is zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a peculiar method for that SDE that goes as follows. I will show just a slightly different case. Assume $-a<0$
$$dX_t=-aX_tdt+\sigma dW_t$$
$$dX_t+aX_tdt=\sigma dW_t$$
Multiply by $e^{at}$
$$dX_te^{at}+aX_te^{at}dt=e^{at}\sigma dW_t$$
$$d(X_te^{at})=e^{at}\sigma dW_t$$
Integrate from $0$ to $t$ assuming $X_0=x_0$ known
$$X_te^{at}-x_0=\sigma\int_0^te^{as}dW_s$$
$$X_t=x_0e^{-at}+\sigma\int_0^te^{-a(t-s)}dW_s$$
So you shouldn't need Ito. In fact, to use Ito you need a 'guess', i.e. $F(t,X_t)=e^{at}X_t$. This is also called 'educated guess' and it is just intuition (of an author). The derivatives are
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=ae^{at}x, \ \ \ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=e^{at}, \ \ \ \ \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}=0$$
So
$$dF=\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dX_t+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}dt=$$
$$=ae^{at}X_tdt-ae^{at}X_tdt+e^{at}\sigma dW_t$$
Thus, by integration,
$$X_te^{at}-x_0=\sigma\int_0^te^{as}dW_s$$
$$X_t=x_0e^{-at}+\sigma\int_0^te^{-a(t-s)}dW_s$$

Comment: what you did is essentially the so-called *stochastic integration by parts*

Comment: Alright, this is a bit out of my bounds as someone new to SDEs. This was just a really hard first problem in my problem set. However, I guess you would have to know this method or have a great intuition to solve this problem. One question I still have though, is why Ito's lemma directly doesn't work? Or is this simply something I have to accept, that Ito's lemma and "matching coefficents" doesn't always yield a solution even though the system of PDES can be solved?

Comment: I understand the bad aftertaste of 'ansatz' solutions, they feel like a trick. In fact they are. 
Your method may work, but I would suggest to stick to safer bets. If you are given the guess, work with it. SDEs are not easily manipulable.

Comment: @SinbadTheSailor This solution also shows why the method of assuming $X_t = f(t,B_t)$ to obtain a PDE for $f$ can't work: $X_t$ depends on the integral $\int_0^t e^{-a(t-s)}dB_s$, which depends on the whole path of the Brownian motion rather than just its value at time $t$.  This suggests that the PDE you obtain will (most likely) not have a solution.  I say "most likely" because it is sometimes possible to express stochastic integrals in terms of the values at just a few points (e.g. $2\int_0^t B_sdB_s = B_t^2-t$), but in general we don't expect that to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account of the comment made by @user6247850 , your analysis is wrong... Instead, try to use $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \sigma$ (which is a constant) to deduce that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial^2 x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = aX_t = a\,f(t,x),$$ then solve $f(t,x)$ directly... Following these lines lead you to $f(t,x) = f(0,x)\,\mathrm{e}^{a\,t}$. But the determination of $f(0,x)$ seems a bit tricky

Comment: Yes, this was what I tired to do. I'll add the remaining part of the solution to show you.

Comment: @SinbadTheSailor I updated my answer as well